# I have one enum which I can't modify and want to add more properties to it

Tags: java, enums

I have one `enum`

```
public enum {
first("prop1", "prop2"), second("prop1", "prop2")
}
```

I can't modify above class.

Now I want to add one more property to same `enum`

```
public enum {
first("prop1", "prop2", "prop3"), second("prop1", "prop2", "prop3")
}
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: You want to modify a class without modifying it?

Comment: i want to use the previous class /enums  with adding more properties to it

Answer (score 3):

Adding a property requires modification. If you cannot modify an `enum`, you cannot add properties to that `enum`.

If you want to associate a new property with an old `enum` that you cannot modify, you can use [`EnumMap<E,T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) to do that:

```
public enum TestEnum {
    first("prop1", "prop2"), second("prop1", "prop2")
}
...
EnumMap<TestEnum,String> prop3 = new EnumMap<TestEnum,String>(TestEnum.class);
prop3.put(TestEnum.first, "FirstProp3");
prop3.put(TestEnum.second, "SecondProp3");
```

Instead of

```
TestEnum tst = ...
String p3 = tst.prop3();
```

you need to write

```
TestEnum tst = ...
String p3 = prop3.get(tst);
```

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is add an EnumMap.  This won't modify the original class but does allow you to specify an additional property.

```
static final Map<MyEnum, String> prop3 = EnumMap.of(MyEnum.class);
static {
    prop3.put(first, "prop3");
    prop3.put(second, "prop3");
}
```

To get this property you can look up

```
String p3 = prop3.get(myEnum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you need

```
public enum {
first("prop1", "prop2", "prop3"), second("prop1", "prop2", "prop3"), third("prop1", "prop2", "prop3")

}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, OP wants to add a third property-parameter to the existing enums, not add a third enum-value.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks for your comment, but why do you think so? OP didn't clarify its question enough to be clear what he wants. In this case you don't understand it correctly and thus wrong.